# Laplace Transform And Getting The Frequent Value For Gyro

Tags: c#, frequency, noise, differential-equations, coordinate-transformation

I'm getting `x,y,z` values from gyro-sensor. Each variable is being sent 10 values per second. In 3 seconds I have;

```
 x=[30values] 
 y=[30values] 
 z=[30values]
```

Some of the values are too different from the others cause of noise. With laplace transform I need to get the most frequent value from my array.

[image: Blockquote]

I need to filter the array with Laplace Transform equation. I need to build the equation in C#. How can I implement the array with the equation?

Comment: This looks like Control/DSP issue... "get the most frequent value from my array" perhaps you can clarify what this means by giving sample input - expected out pair. This way, it is easier to understand the issue or proposing solution. For instance, what are the values for x = [30 values] and what is the expected output

Comment: For example: x=[301,302,306,301,305,_512_,308,301,302,_616_,306...] I need to use the Laplace Transformation to get the frequency values of x coordinate in case of understanding the 301-308 values are the most accurate numbers. But how can I implement the array with the equation?

Comment: Oh, oh, not here... You may update the question.. And things may get a lot easier if you do not require the filter to be Laplace, but any filter (such as median/mean)..

Comment: Yeah you are exactly right, but I need to use the Laplace Transformation :/ And I don't have any idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this kind of filter (Laplace) is very specialized to certain area of `Engineering` and needs a person who has good understanding on both the programming language (in this case is C#) and the filter itself, I would recommend you to use such [source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25189/Numerical-Laplace-Transforms-and-Inverse-Transform), rather than code the filter by yourself.

Here is the snippet of the source code:

```
class Laplace 
{ 
    const int DefaultStehfest = 14; 
    public delegate double FunctionDelegate(double t); 
    static double[] V; // Stehfest coefficients 
    static double ln2; // log of 2

    public static void InitStehfest(int N) 
    { 
        ln2 = Math.Log(2.0); 
        int N2 = N / 2; 
        int NV = 2 * N2; 
        V = new double[NV]; 
        int sign = 1; 
        if ((N2 % 2) != 0) 
            sign = -1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < NV; i++) 
        { 
            int kmin = (i + 2) / 2; 
            int kmax = i + 1; 
            if (kmax > N2) 
                kmax = N2; 
            V[i] = 0; 
            sign = -sign; 
            for (int k = kmin; k <= kmax; k++) 
            { 
                V[i] = V[i] + (Math.Pow(k, N2) / Factorial(k)) * (Factorial(2 * k) 
                     / Factorial(2 * k - i - 1)) / Factorial(N2 - k) 
                     / Factorial(k - 1) / Factorial(i + 1 - k); 
            } 
            V[i] = sign * V[i]; 
        } 
    }

    public static double InverseTransform(FunctionDelegate f, double t) 
    { 
        double ln2t = ln2 / t; 
        double x = 0; 
        double y = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++) 
        { 
            x += ln2t; 
            y += V[i] * f(x); 
        } 
        return ln2t * y; 
    } 

    public static double Factorial(int N) 
    { 
        double x = 1; 
        if (N > 1) 
        { 
            for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) 
                x = i * x; 
        } 
        return x; 
    } 
}
```

coded by Mr. Walt Fair Jr. in CodeProject.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will look at it.

Comment: You are welcome. The idea here is not to create something which you could not afford by yourself... Since in very specialized area like `Control/DSP Engineering`, it is easy to make mistake in coding, either because we are not familiar with the language or with the `Engineering` concept. So, unless you are very sure or there isn't any other who do such thing, I would rather recommend to look for better solution outside first...

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your answers and guidance again!